# prestashop product names, descriptions and prices

Tags: prestashop

I have a question and I cannot find any answers. I need to get all prestashop product names, descriptions and prices. Does anyone have code sample or just know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Advanced Parameters -> SQL Manager and add and run the following query:

```
SELECT
    a.`id_product`,
    b.`name` AS `name`,
    b.`description`,
    `reference`,
    a.`price` AS `price`

FROM
    `ps_product` a     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_product_lang` b 
        ON (
            b.`id_product` = a.`id_product` 
            AND b.`id_lang` = 1 
            AND b.`id_shop` = 1
        )       
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_stock_available` sav 
        ON (
            sav.`id_product` = a.`id_product` 
            AND sav.`id_product_attribute` = 0    
            AND sav.id_shop = 1  
            AND sav.id_shop_group = 0 
        )  
JOIN
    `ps_product_shop` sa 
        ON (
            a.`id_product` = sa.`id_product` 
            AND sa.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
        )     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_category_lang` cl 
        ON (
            sa.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category` 
            AND b.`id_lang` = cl.`id_lang` 
            AND cl.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
        )     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_shop` shop 
        ON (
            shop.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
        )     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_image_shop` image_shop 
        ON (
            image_shop.`id_product` = a.`id_product` 
            AND image_shop.`cover` = 1 
            AND image_shop.id_shop = a.id_shop_default
        )     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_image` i 
        ON (
            i.`id_image` = image_shop.`id_image`
        )     
LEFT JOIN
    `ps_product_download` pd 
        ON (
            pd.`id_product` = a.`id_product` 
            AND pd.`active` = 1
        )      
WHERE
    1            
ORDER BY
    a.`id_product` ASC
```

You can also export it to CSV. It's a bit more complicated than you need it because it was generated by Prestashop's "Export to SQL manager" functionality that you can find in products view.